# Probability of choosing C out of T students with restrictions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is a class of $T$ students, consisting of $G$ girls and $(T - G)$ boys. Out of the $T$ students, only $C$ are selected for an examination. What is the probability that there are ***at least*** $K$ girls , in the $C$ students selected?
I've solved the problem using combinations. But for very large $T$, computing combinations doesn't seem right. I'm looking for a faster solution.

My solution: 
$$n(K) = \binom{G}K\binom{T - G}{C-K}+\binom{G}{K + 1}\binom{T - G}{C - (K + 1)}+\binom{G}{K + 2}\binom{T - G}{C - (K + 2)}+ ....+\binom{G}C\binom{T - G}0$$
$$T = \binom{T}C$$ 
$$P = \frac{n(K)}{T} \ .$$

Is there a way to altogether avoid combinations here?

PS: I'm looking to code the solution, but I would like to know the math behind it. $T$ may go up to 1000.

Comment: This might help: Ling & Pratt (1984). An empirical study of several hypergeometric approximations. 

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2288333?uid=3739560&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21101991685213

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20binom%20%28G,j%29%20%2a%20binom%20%28T-G,C-j%29%20for%20j=K..C) gives a result in terms of the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function):

$$
\sum_{j=K}^C\binom Gj\binom{T-G}{C-j}\\=\binom GK\binom{T-G}{C-K}{}_3F_2(1,K-C,K-G;K+1,K+T-C-G+1;1)\;.
$$