# Problem on conditional probability

Tags: probability

We have a set of $s$ elements and we choose $n$ elements, where $n \le s$, from it randomly. There are $M$ special numbers (including $M'$). What is the probability of choosing $n$ elements from $s$, which contains at least $k$ special numbers given that $M'$ is in selected elements?

Comment: When you choose $n$ from $s$ elements, is it with replacement or without replacement? Also, what do you mean by "including $M'$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll make the following assumptions about the intent of the question: The $M$ "special numbers" are elements of the set of $s$ elements. (It would have been clearer to call them "special elements", as the remaining elements are not limited to numbers and the restriction of the special elements to numbers isn't being used anywhere.) The name $M'$ refers to one of the $M$ special numbers. (It would have been clearer to use two different letters here, since one is a count of elements and the other is an element.)

Under these assumptions, the question can be reduced to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383593) by first removing the element $M'$ known to be among the selected elements; i.e., substitute $n-1$ for $C$, $s-1$ for $T$, $k-1$ for $K$ and $M-1$ for $G$.